# How to extract lines from source file with reference file, add to result file?

Tags: shell-script

I have the over simplified  source & reference files.

source file, `s.txt`:

```
dn: cn=user1, cn=users,dc=domain
changetype: modify
replace: userpassword
userpassword: {SSHA}$%^&

dn: cn=user2, cn=users,dc=domain
changetype: modify
replace: userpassword
userpassword: {SSHA}$%^&dffd

dn: cn=user3, cn=users,dc=domain
changetype: modify
replace: userpassword
userpassword: {SSHA}$%^&dfd32
```

reference file, `r.txt`:

```
dn: cn=user2, cn=users,dc=domain
```

I want a script for using the reference record dn file to extract the source file's user2'dn line and 3 lines after,  add to a result file `user_chg.ldif`.

`user_chg.ldif`:

```
dn: cn=user2, cn=users,dc=domain
changetype: modify
replace: userpassword
userpassword: {SSHA}$%^&dffd
```

Comment: Will you reference files have multiple entries or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
while read LINE; do
  sed -n -e "/^$LINE\$/,/^$/p" s.txt
done < r.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

How about (if your `grep` version allows for the `-A` option):

```
grep -A3 -f r.txt s.txt
```

Comment: You should probably use `-F` too to treat the pattern as a string rather than as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for RalfFriedl's answer for my question.
I have a slight different question and cannot figure out. 
s.txt source file:

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=user1,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=user10,cn=users,dc=domain

r.txt reference file:
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain
uniquemember: cn=user8,cn=users,dc=domain

I'd want a script for using the reference record uniquemember file to extract the source file's user9's line and 3 lines Above, add to a result file usermember_add.ldif.

dn: cn=task,cn=Groups,dc=domain
changetype: modify
add: uniquemember
uniquemember: cn=user9,cn=users,dc=domain

Comment: Could anyone help?